# vue-form-generator & vue-multiselect: can't remove tags, duplicates them

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-multiselect

I am using [`vue-form-generator`](https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator) with the field [`vueMultiselect`](https://vue-generators.gitbook.io/vue-generators/fields/optional_fields/vuemultiselect) (integration of [`vue-multiselect`](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect)).

**Adding tags works well**, however **deleting tags fails** (clicking on `x` icon):

- nothing happens when trying to delete the first existing tag
- if you add a tag and try to delete it, a `input` event is emitted which duplicates tags

For instance:

- Starts with `Vue.js`
- Click `x` on `Vue.js` ==> tag remains, (**BROKEN**)
- Add `Rails.js` ==>  `Vue.js`, `Rails.js` (**OK**)
- Click `x` on `Rails.js` ==> `Vue.js`, `Vue.js`, `Rails.js` (**BROKEN**)

[Here is a link to reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/epo8mxqf/7/)

[image]

---

**Q: Is this failing because I misconfigured [`vueMultiselect`](https://vue-generators.gitbook.io/vue-generators/fields/optional_fields/vuemultiselect) (eg some options I need to set to prevent this behaviour)?**

If not I'll just raise it as a bug

`Versions`:

- Vue = 2.5.17
- vue-multiSelect = 2.1.2
- vue-form-generator = 2.3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this `codepen` maybe this will help you.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/73ufp4ys/

According to this [Github issue](https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator/issues/666) it's simply because the `trackBy` option was missing.

Comment: Yes it works: what's specifically caused my code to fail?